# Determining worst-case time-complexity of this function?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I'm currently studying sets from Richard Hammack's 'Book of Proof' and I was trying to implement a set to a power (more specifically, the cartesian power of a set). An example of this is as follows:
Suppose I have set A = {0, 1}, then
A<sup>2</sup> = {0, 1} x {0, 1} = {(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)}

I successfully implemented a general function that could raise a set to any power I specified. The code is as follows:

```
def add_to_tuple(tup, a):
    tup = list(tup)
    tup.append(a)
    return tuple(tup)


def multiply(A, B):
    return_set = []
    for a in A:
        for b in B:
            if type(a) is tuple and type(b) is tuple:
                return_set.append(a + b)
            elif type(a) is not tuple and type(b) is tuple:
                return_set.append(add_to_tuple(b, a))
            elif type(a) is tuple and type(b) is not tuple:
                return_set.append(add_to_tuple(a, b))
            else:
                return_set.append((a, b))
    return return_set


def set_to_power(finite_set, power):
    if power == 1:
        return finite_set
    else:
        return multiply(finite_set, set_to_power(finite_set, power - 1))

a = [0, 1]
print(set_to_power(a, 2))
```

The following output is:`[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]`
I'm trying to figure out the time complexity of `set_to_power` and I'm not sure whether it's n<sup>2</sup> or not.

Comment: Don't use `set` as variable name. You are shadowing built-in set definition.

Comment: Noted! I'll change my code, should I replace those variable names as well in my question?

Comment: It certainly wouldn't hurt

Comment: Changed ```set``` variables to ```finite_set```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at all the functions one by one -

### `1.add_to_tuple(tup, a)`

This function is **`O(n)`** where `n` is length of tuple. Within the function, the `tup = list(tup)` is `O(n)` same with final `tuple(tup)` where `tup` is list. In python, the conversion between `tuple` <--> `list` is `O(n)` since python needs to copy all items in the `list`/`tuple` to another. So use a `list` while you are adding members in the list and in the end you can convert your `list` to `tuple` if you want to.

### `2.multiply(A, B)`

This is `O(len(A) * len(B) * O(add_to_tuple)`, since we are looping through all items in `A` and `B` and then calling the `add_to_tuple` for each of them = **`O(n^3)`** where `n` is length of set(A)

### `3.set_to_power(finite_set, power)`

Let's say `power` is `k`, and initial length of the `finite_set` is `n`. We will be calling the `multiply` function `k` times, during each call to `multiply` function, the resulting `finite_set` is going to be become `n` times the pervious size.
e.g. with `[0, 1]` and `[0, 1, 2]` being `finite_set`

```
>>> set_to_power([0, 1], 1)
[0, 1]
>>> set_to_power([0, 1], 2)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> set_to_power([0, 1], 3)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1)]
>>> set_to_power([0, 1, 2], 1)
[0, 1, 2]
>>> set_to_power([0, 1, 2], 2)
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
>>> set_to_power([0, 1, 2], 3)
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 2, 0), (1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0), (2, 2, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1), (0, 2, 1), (1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 2, 1), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 1), (2, 2, 1), (0, 0, 2), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 2), (1, 0, 2), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 0, 2), (2, 1, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
```

So the total complexity is going to be -

```
First call to multiply - O(n^3) +
Second call to multiply, the new finite_set will be of length n*n - O((n*n)^3) + 
Third call to multiply - O((n*n*n)^3) + ... k times
```

which is **`O(N^3k)`** for your solution.

---

You can reduce your complexity down to `O(N^2k)` by fixing the conversions in `add_to_tuple` and using `lists` instead which have an amortized `O(1)` complexity for `append` operation.

As a side note, the optimal solution for the problem would have its complexity as `O(k*N^k)`, since there will be `N^K` items in the resulting set each of length `k`. What you are generating basically are all items of length `k` which are permutations of a given initial set where each element can be repeated(see the output of `set_to_power([0, 1, 2], 3)` above for example). We can start with an element which is [0, 0, 0] and then add it to our answer, and then in each step keep increasing the last digit which needs to be increased

```
e.g. [0, 0, 0] -> [0, 0, 1] -> [0, 0, 2] -> [0, 1, 0] -> [0, 1, 1] ...
```

each step can be `O(k)`, since you need to create a copy of previous list and then modify it in place to next digit in `O(1)` time. This would result in `O(k*N^k)` solution.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is very concise and easy to understand.

Comment: Also, is it N^(3k) or k*N^3?

Comment: Its `N^(3k)`, also some info about the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for the optimal solution! I accepted your answer. I can't upvote your answer because I don't have enough reputation yet haha.

Answer (score 0):

First let's look at `multiply`:
You've got 2 nested for loops with no breaks or returns, so whatever is in them will be executed len(A) * len(B) times. `add_to_tuple` depends on the size of a tuple; I'll get to that later, for now let's assume base case of power = 2 so `add_to_tuple` does not happen. In that case they are constant, so everything apart from for loops is in O(1) time. So yeah, your multiply will run in O(n^2) time for power 2.

Trouble starts when we get to `set_to_power` function - it has 2 parameters, both of which affect the complexity of the function. So it certainly won't be O(n^2) - we have to take into account the power variable somehow.
First of all, your add_to_tuple is O(i) *(like 90% sure, although I'm not certain about inner workings of list() and tuple())* in terms of the power variable. So this already means each run of `multiply` will take O(i*(n^2)).
Then you are triggering that i times, each time with n times more elements in one of the sets.
I thiiiiink it's gonna be something like ~ O(i^2 * n * n^i) (i is roughly power-1, but I'm not sure how is that relevant in Big-O notation.)